# Codeigniter null values ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

, i'm triying to get some values from database on an ajax request in codeigniter...but json object returns null ([]) when I put console.log...I need help pls !!

JAVASCRIPT

```
function list_president() {
        var section = "1";
        $.post(baseurl + 'votos/load_politic', section,
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function load_politic()
{
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

      $section = $this->input->post('section');
    $result  = $this->politic->get_president($section);

    echo json_encode($result);
  }
}
```

MODEL

```
public function get_president($section){


  $this->db->select("p.POLITIC_NAME, p.POLITIC_LASTNAME, p.POLITIC_SIDE, p.POLITIC_CHARGE");
  $this->db->from("politics p");
  $this->db->where("SECTION_ID",$section);

  $result= $this->db->get();

  return $result->result();
}
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: If you are getting this by id, then you are fetching one row, so you need to return $result->row(). After this please in your $.post call just console.log(data) and tell me what you get.

Comment: @Franco I have change $result->result(); ...for $result->row() ...and return null =(

Comment: @charlietfl has pointed you to the right direction, this has escaped to my attention because I always use an ajax cal for those kind of things. But I hope that his suggestion has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending key/value pair to server...just a value.

So there is no `$_POST['section']` which is basically what  `$this->input->post('section');` is

Try changing

```
 var section = "1";
```

To

```
 var section = {section: "1"};
```

You also aren't validating what is sent or checking if `$result` returns anything